# number of occurrences by lines R

Tags: r, find-occurrences

I have this array:

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1
 [38] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [75] 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
[112] 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2
```

And I want to count the number of occurrences of '1' and '2'. From [1] to [70] and from [71] to the end.

I tried :

```
sum(x==1)
```

But this for all.How can I select lines?

Comment: or `table(x[1:70])` and `table(x[-(1:70)])`

Comment: Check out any introductory text about R - read the bits about "subsetting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function sum {base} should return the sum of all the values present in its arguments

you could define the arguments the following way:
with x[a:b] you can set boundaries (for example a=1 and b=10, will set the area from [1] to[10]);
with the operator == you can check if one specific value c is present between your boundaries ... e.g.:  x[a:b]==c
if you want to look for more than one value ( for example c & d , where c==1 and d==2 , you can (for example) use a simple addition to sum up your results:

Now you can just say: sum(x[a:b]==c) + sum(x[a:b]==c)
Where a&b are your boundaries and c&d are the values you want to compare.

Comment: Hi, I have another question. I want to get this values but automatically. I mean, is there any function in R which will automatically give me number of occurences of the maximum value? If it is '2' automatically return the numbers of '2' in the selected vector.Thanks